# Mysql table design advice

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-performance

I have a general question about MySQL database table design. I have a table that contains ~ 650 thousand records, with approximately 100 thousand added per year. The data is requested quite frequently, 1.6 times per second on average.

It has the following structure right now

```
id   port_id         date        product1_price    product2_price    product3_price
 1         1   2012-01-01                100.00            200.00            155.00
 2         2   2012-01-01                  NULL            150.00            255.00
 3         3   2012-01-01                300.00              NULL            355.00
 4         1   2012-01-02                200.00            250.00            355.00
 5         2   2012-01-02                400.00            230.00            255.00
```

Wouln't it be better to store the data in this manner?

```
id     port_id         date    product   price
1            1   2012-01-01          1     100
1            2   2012-01-01          1     200
1            3   2012-01-01          1     300
1            1   2012-01-02          1     240
```

Advantages of the alternative design:

- with the second design we don't have to store NULL values (if there is no such product in the port)
- we can add new products easily - comparing to the first design, where each new product requires a new column

Disadvantages of the alternative design:

- The number of records will increase from 650 000 to 650 000 * number_of_products minus all NULL records; that will be approximately 2.1 million records.

In both cases we have `id` column as PRIMARY_KEY and UNIQUE key on combination of `port_id` and `date`.

So the question is: which way to go? Disk space does not matter, the speed of the queries is the most important aspect.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

It seams, that will depend on definition of `product` table.
If product table is statically compound of maximum three parts, then changing the current design won't help much.
Although the current design smells bad but that will be a business dependent analysis.
BTW change must be done with caution on the side effects with product table and its usages.